Angular Reset Password User or Password Not Found
I have an issue when user chooses forgot password.  The forgot password form appears user enters email, user get's alert to check there email and  user clicks link which  take you to reset form. The user type in new password password. I get alert saying password reset successful.   User gets routed to login page.   When I type in new password and it says Password or User name is incorrect. So its not being updated. I'm thinking it has something to do with way I'm doing my update. It not being updated in database.  My console.log  and alerts confirm its reaching service and endpoints.   If someone can please point me in the right direction I would be so grateful. .  I have included only necessary code snippet:
Reset Password Component:
 let resetObj={
 token: this.token,
  Password: this.form.value.password
 }

 //This gets called on submit
  this.accountService.resetPassword(resetObj)

      .subscribe({
          next: () => {
              this.alertService.success('Password reset successful, you can now login', 
               { keepAfterRouteChange: true });
                this.form.reset();
                this.router.navigate(['../../login'], { relativeTo: this.route });
              },
          error: error => {
              this.alertService.error(error);
           
          }
      });

accountService:
  resetPassword(resetObj: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/reset-password`,  resetObj);
  }

endpoint:
controller.js
  router.post('/reset-password', passwordReset)

 function passwordReset(req,res, next){
 console.log("Does it goet to password reset");

     const token = req.body.token;
     const newPassword = req.body.password; 
     
     console.log("What do  properties hold" + " " + " " + newPassword + " " + " " + 
      token)
       userService.resetPassword(token, newPassword)
       .then(() =>res.json({}))
        .catch(err => next(err));          

   }

userservice:
   async function resetPassword(token,  newPassword, result,res){

    console.log("InsideresetPassword Service")
    console.log("whats in token", token); 
    console.log("What is new password", newPassword);


     jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_Secret, async(err, data) =>{
    console.log("Does it get to this if")
      if(err){
        console.log("Reset Link is Expired");
      }else{ 
        console.log("Does it get to else in reset service")
        const response = data;
        const user = await User.findOne({email: {$regex: '^'+ response.email+"$", 
        $options: 'i'}});
        console.log("Whats email", user.email)
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt);
        user.password = encryptedPassword;
       
        try{
            const updateUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
               {_id: user._id},
               {$set: user},
               {new: true}  //can show update
             
            )
           
              console.log( "Password Updated")
            

          }catch(error){
            console.log("Something went wrong while redirecting passwor


          }
        

        }


      
     })

 } 
  


Try  const update = {password: await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, salt)}; await User.findOneAndUpdate( {_id: user._id}, update,{new: true})

@Oscar Can you explain why?  They're already awaiting the hash?

resetObj has Password, while the server has req.body.password.  I'm guessing it's not the easy, but you never know.  Please post all the log output, except redact the token and password as REDACTED_TOKEN and REDACTED_PASSWORD.

@MatthewFlaschen, Yes, what im saying is that he should try to update with a plain object instead of the User document object that is returned from the findOne. As is own answer states, he is now passing the plain object with  the field "hash" that we were not aware of.

I find myself at times answering my own question after I ask it.
This one was a bit easier than I thought. It seems we sometimes look
for more difficult solutions.  Adding console.log helps in stepping through
my code. It was just like I thought an update issue. The newPasword was not being updated in the database. Looking at my schema helped as well.
One I did the first findOne() by email  as was able to console.log it I knew I was on the right track.
$set:{"hash":user.password}},
was all I had to change.
Hope this helps someone.
PDH
